# Google maps showing wrong current location in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I have added Google maps to my flutter app and I am trying to hive it initialize to my current location. When I open the map page the current location is in Mountainview California but I live in Florida.

Why is this happening?

Here is the code I am using and it works except for the current location:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MapPropertySearchResults extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapPropertySearchResults({super.key});

  @override
  State<MapPropertySearchResults> createState() =>
      _MapPropertySearchResultsState();
}

class _MapPropertySearchResultsState extends State<MapPropertySearchResults> {
    late GoogleMapController mapController;

  late LatLng _currentPosition;
  bool _isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocation();
  }

  getLocation() async {
    LocationPermission permission;
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();

    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    double lat = position.latitude;
    double long = position.longitude;

    LatLng location = LatLng(lat, long);

    setState(() {
      _currentPosition = location;
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Map'),
      ),
      body: _isLoading ? 
      const Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator()) : 
      GoogleMap(
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: _currentPosition,
          zoom: 16.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Could it be a setting on my computer?
Thanks

Comment: Are you running this on the Android Emulator?

Comment: The Android emulator have a functionality where you can change the mock location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use an android simulator? If you do, that's standard practice since it replicates Google's headquarters location

Alternatively, on iOS, the default location of the iOS simulator is "1 Stockton St, San Francisco, 94108, United States"